# How to hide a website's element in webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I'm using webview in android studio and i would like to load my website but I also want to hide some elements (because it's the mobile version).
Is it possible to achieve this by some way in android webview?

Comment: what do you meant by hide some element.

Comment: you can hide them with the JS. Just first figure out which JS you need to execute to hide whatever you want, and then you only need to find out how to execute JS in the WebView (should take not more than 30 sec to search)

Comment: @nikos fotomaras simply create some webpages for android .so that it will easy to load.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide an element of the website in WebView by executing JavaScript function into WebView. I will post a link of youtube tutorial which will clear your confusion how we can get element id then hide. I will strongly recommend you to watch the tutorial but the tutorial is in the Hindi language. you will understand the core concept by only watching it.

Youtube Tutorial: [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgk81fT52i4&index=11&list=PLRKyZvuMYSIOFU_38SBsu3JVnjjvgx-67)

Here is a small example of executing JavaScript function in WebView.

```
    WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);  
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        // hide element by class name
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementsByClassName('your_class_name')[0].style.display='none'; })()");
        // hide element by id
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementById('your_id').style.display='none';})()");

    }
    });

webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: I posted this so you can get the idea from it. Have you watched the tutorial ?

Comment: yeap i watched the tut and i'm going to test it once more using another class name .All i want to do is hide some elements in webview to change their location. I mean i want a dropdown bar to appear on the top left side of the webpage when im in webview

Answer (score 0):

You should get the source html from outside the webview, then parse it as raw data, modify what you want, and give the webview your processed html.

getting html data from url:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Create HTTP Client
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://yoururl.com"); // Set the action you want to do
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); // Executeit
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the response
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read line by line
    sb.append(line + "\n");

String resString = sb.toString(); // Result is here

is.close(); // Close the stream
```

After getting html removes element that you want to remove and pass that html to Webview.